# How to verify Subversion working copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a Subversion working copy with at least one missing file (the local copy got removed while fixing a tree conflict). It's funny because the file is versioned, it appears in the repository, the tree conflict resolution was 100% local (it happened on update and I didn't commit afterwards) and I've run "svn cleanup" several times but none of my Subversion clients (command line svn and TortoiseSVN) can detect the working copy is corrupted. Not even reverting all changes got the file back.

I'll fix it as usual (fresh checkout somewhere else and copy changes with WinMerge); I actually have a different question:

How can you test the validity of a working copy?

Of course, you can always check out a new copy and use a file compare utility but... isn't there a better way? Is there a tool to verify a working copy equivalent to `svnadmin verify`?

**=== UPDATE ===**

I've got nice answers with tricks to prevent working copy corruption but my question was more on the line of finding a method to be 100% sure that the working copy is both coherent and linked with the actual repository contents; in other works, a working copy equivalent of the **svnadmin verify** command.

So far, it looks like:

- Subversion doesn't provide such tool and it's possible that the SVN data format does not even allow to write one.
- Updating to a revision is a technique that seems to find (and fix) some issues, although you often need to revert back and forth to an old revision and I suppose it can only detect missing files if they have been changed in the revision range.
- Checking out a fresh working copy looks like the only 100% reliable method.

Comment: I've had similar problems - renaming folders seems to cause an issue at times, though not every time. *Usually*, a revert will bring the working copy back to a valid state, though with unversioned items (the "copy" side of the renamed folder) left behind. But yes, I'd like a validity check tool as well.

Comment: Possibly, the issue is that the working copy state is valid, just not what you think it should be. For example, it is valid for a working copy to exclude certain files or folders that are in the repository. Just because a state is confusing and isn't what you intended, doesn't mean it can't arise legitimately, in which case the "error" isn't detectable. A "state of this working copy" tool which lists anything "interesting" might be more useful.

Comment: @Steve314: The base contents of the working copy must be identical to those in the repository. Subversion is a centralized version control system so this is a required condition and it should be detectable. Of course, the tool you describe would also be great (for instance, I'd love to learn when I have .svn dirs from different repositories) but that's a different story.

Comment: I've had this problem a few times with missing files (user A adds files, they show in the svn browser, but user B's IDE doesn't know they're missing and are ignored in updates). The only solution I've found is to do a fully recursive update-to-version-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I'll have to assume that there isn't a reliable way to do it unless you do a new commit and compare both directory trees. If a `.snv` directory is missing data but is not actually damaged, there just isn't enough information in the working copy to detect some files are gone.

While it's possible that [WC-NG](http://prng.blogspot.com/2010/04/what-is-subversions-wc-ng.html) changes this for better (or not), current format is not that rock-solid.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a problem that I experienced some time ago: [svn - file in working copy seems "lost"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711885/svn-file-in-working-copy-seems-lost)

quoting wcoenen's answer verbatim:

> SVN 1.6.1 clients (including
>   TortoiseSVN) had a bug where folders
>   would sometimes erroneously be set to
>   depth "empty". This causes the
>   symptoms you describe. (Note that it's
>   possible that the folder was made
>   "empty" by svn 1.6.1 and has remained
>   that way even though you've already
>   upgraded to a newer svn client in the
>   mean time.)
>
> To fix it, use the "update to
>   revision" menu item in TortoiseSVN and
>   select the depth "fully recursive"

Comment: It looks good at first sight. In my test copy, this method has recovered the missing file.

Comment: False alarm. I've tested in two working copies I have that point to the same location and revision: one of them is missing a versioned file and "Update to revision" does nothing to recover the file (or even warn there's something wrong).

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on the file, under the SVN menu I believe there is a command called Diff. This will open and highlight the differences between the local version and the repo version I believe.

You can also execute diff from the command line if you wish.

Comment: Interesting... If I use the "Diff with URL" menu item of TortoiseSVN to compare the working copy with the repository trunk I finally get an error message: The path
<i>D:/Project/working-copy/missing-file.php</i>
in the patchfile does not exist.
TortoiseMerge tried to apply the patch by stripping prefixes but no matching path could be found.

Comment: @Steve314: Did you miss the `tortoisesvn` tag?

Comment: @sbi - yes, and it looks like I'm wrong on the other count too - oh well.

Comment: Sorry, I added the tortoisesvn tag later. The program was mentioned in the question but I mistakenly thought it wasn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems when I was beginning to work with SVN using Tortoise on Windows. Whenever I needed a to copy a folder - e.g. when creating a new plug-in that was based on another, already existing one - I merrily copy+pasted it within the working copy.

What I didn't know was that when you do that, you copy along the `.svn` metadata directory. This causes subversion endless confusion - if you work with a graphical client, the new directory seems to be properly checked in, and the client  shows you a clean plate after each commit. But, *the new directory never gets checked in*.

You notice this when you check out a new working copy elsewhere, and then you're screwed because those files never were under version control. Cost me half a day to fix back then.

When you need duplicate a directory in a working copy, always export it first, then add it back.